# Adding a forward slash using cleanURL assets stop working

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

Im doing a website for a school project and I was looking into using cleanURL so I followed this tutorial www. you tube.com/watch?v=ZgCW2x5QCXo, when i put /studytips/home it works perfectly fine but if i add a / or something it stops working.
Images of what happens[Without the /foo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3jOv.jpg)
[With the /foo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI21W.jpg)
I will include his class, to use it i do the following:

```
if($url->segment(1)){
    $s1=($url->segment(1));
    if((file_exists("includes/$s1.php"))){
        include("includes/$s1.php");
    } else {
        include("includes/404.php");
    }               
}else include("includes/home.php");
```

i came up with the hadling of it not sure if it is the best approach^

```
class simpleUrl{

    var $site_path;

    function __construct($site_path){
        $this->site_path= $this->removeSlash($site_path);

    }

    function __toString(){
        return $this->site_path;
    }
    private function removeSlash($string){
        if( $string[strlen($string)-1] == '/')
            $string =rtrim($string,'/');


        return $string;
    }

    function segment($segment){

        $url = str_replace($this->site_path,'' , $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $url = explode('/',$url);

        if(isset($url[$segment]) )

            return $url[$segment];
        return $url;
    }

}
```

htaccess file:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /copy/studytips/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /copy/studytips/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php/$1
```

Which works with or without `/`, but in any case returns the `/` in de rewrite url.

Comment: If your problem is only with css and images, you need to add: `<base href="/">`  in your html `<head>`.

Comment: I didn't understand, should I replace the <link> tags with the <base> tags?

Comment: No, just add the `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` part of your html file. And after that all the links are relative to the domain root. And nothing change if you use more or less `/` in your final link

Comment: Thank you so much, i tried `<base href="/">` but it didnt work so i did `<base href="/copy/studytips/">` and it worked thank you this has going been annoying me for literally one week

Comment: You're welcome, `<base href="/">` was if all your links were related to the root. But you can effectively utilize the nearest folder.